# ImportError: No module named function

Tags: python, linux, terminal, importerror

Hello I am new to python, so I apologize if this is a stupid question. I am working through a tutorial for python, and I'm stuck on one of the first exercises!

I have a file called filename created in a text editor (sublime) saved in `/home/emily/Documents/pythonfiles`. I'm using Ubuntu. Inside that file I have the following python code:

```
def functionname():
    print("hello")
```

I change my directory to `/Documents/pythonfiles` in the terminal. I then load python by typing `python`. Then after getting the confirmation that python loaded, I type `from filename import functionname`. I get the following error.

```
ImportError: No module named filename
```

I searched for a solution online, and found that it might be a problem with python not looking in the right directory. So I execute the following in the Ubuntu shell.

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/emily/Documents/pythonfiles
```

However, I still get the same error as I did previously. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your file called `filename` or `filename.py`? It needs to have the `.py` extension in order to be imported.

Comment: My file was just named filename. I saved it under filename.py, and now it works perfectly. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that filename is in this directory? As you can read under this link https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html in section 6.1.2. The Module Search Path:

The directory containing the script being run is placed at the beginning of the search path, ahead of the standard library path.

Did you check what variable sys.path contains?

Also, the file should be named "filename.py", not "filename".

Comment: As MattDMo pointed out above, the problem was that the file was named filename and not filename.py like you also mentioned. I renamed my file and now it works. Thanks for your help.